# How can I create a remote connection between Mac & Windows computers?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop, remote-access

My office has 30 Windows PCs and 5 iMacs, all of which are connected to a LAN and the internet.

I have seen TeamViewer being used for accessing other computers remotely, and want to know if it is possible to make remote connections like that between Mac OS X and Windows?

Specifically, can someone access a Mac remotely from a Windows PC with some kind of remote login? If so how, and what software is needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using any one of the numerous VNC programs. I prefer UltraVNC:

http://www.uvnc.com/

UltraVNC will be great on the Windows side, and for setting up the Macs, these directions should help:

[Wiki-How Article on setting up VNC on OS X](http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X)

They will both play nicely with each other. You will be able to connect from Mac to Windows and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Apple machines provide remote desktop support via its own app or a VNC viewer.  There's a windows remote desktop client for mac if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 4):

If it was for non-commercial use I'd recommend [LogMeIn Free](http://logmein.com), which is easier to setup and administer than VNC - I mostly use TightVNC or UltraVNC.

Comment: I have found LogMeIn to be so much faster than VNC when controlling a Mac from Windows.

Comment: I think LogMeIn is free for *personal* use, not for *non-commercial* use. TeamViewer is free for all non-commercial use, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

If the Mac has Leopard or above, it already has remote desktop support; you just need to enable it under Preferences, set up a VNC viewer on your Windows machine, and link the two. From Windows, I use PuTTY to ssh into my Mac with a tunnel for the vnc port and then open up TightVNC to view and control my Mac's desktop. (Setting up a secure tunnel might not be necessary since all of your computers are networked though.) You may find this useful:

[Remote Desktop Into Mac OS X Leopard From Windows](http://www.whenbrainsfly.com/2009/01/remote-desktop-into-mac-os-x-leopard-from-windows/).

Answer (score 2):

**[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)**, the fastest Remote Access solution (Windows & Mac) now with voice and video chat support.

*TeamViewer is free for personal use.*

Comment: I think TeamViewer is free for all *non-commercial* use (probably including *personal* use).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your network setup and your needs, you can use the built-in VNC as stated above, but you can also use free or non free remote access softwares like Yuuguu or SparkAngels.

See refs : http://technologie.fgranger.com/index.php/post/2009/05/11/Control-a-Mac-remotely