# Remote desktop from Windows 7 to OS X

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Connection Between Mac & Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/51863/remote-connection-between-mac-windows)

Can anyone suggest a good free solution for to remote desktop from a windows pc to a mac box?

Answer (score 1):

There are several free VNC clients that will let you do this - first install the server program (for example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/ ) on the Mac, then you can use something like TightVNC: http://www.tightvnc.com/ or UltraVNC: http://www.ultravnc.com/ to connect.

Comment: Seconded, use the built-in VNC server (System Preferences / Sharing / Screen Sharing) rather than installing another program. You can use just about any VNC client to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx will work on Windows, Mac, Linux, IPhone, and IPad. This is free for noncommercial use.